# Prevent Flask Server From Including FIN bit in Response to Client

Tags: python, flask, tcp

I'm working with a Flask server in a test environment. After each HTTP packet it receives from a client, it sends an HTTP 200 OK packet that includes a FIN bit. Is there anyway to change the socket configuration on the server side to keep the connection open between reception of HTTP packets from the client?

Comment: Sounds like you want to trade your HTTP-request for a websocket

Comment: What you want is HTTP keep-alive. Hopefully the linked question provides what you need. If not please add more details about your setup (both client and server) to your question (edit question, not comment) and ask for the question to reopen.

Comment: I do have "WSGIRequestHandler.protocol_version = "HTTP/1.1" in my main before the app.run call launches the socket, which based on my reading of that duplicate should achieve keep-alive, no?